# Next.js redirect URL based on regex expression not working

Tags: reactjs, regex, next.js

I want to redirect all requests coming from `/experiences/554\\*\\` (e.g., `/experiences/554-some-string`) to `/experiences/430-lp-v-fm`.

I tried this:

```
  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/experiences/554\\*\\',
      destination: '/experiences/430-lp-v-fm',
      permanent: true,
    },
  ],
```

But it works only for `/experiences/554`.

What regex should I use?

Comment: The first backslash will escape the second in ``\\``. Then, I believe the regex engine will get the backslash and the star `\*`, and it will then escape the star to not have its special meaning, and as a result try to match a literal *. `/experiences/554.*` should match `/experiences/554-some-string`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the `\\` is used to escape special characters which is not what you need in this scenario. Instead you can simply use `(.*)` to match anything after `/554`.

```js
module.exports = {
    redirects: async () => [
        {
            source: '/experiences/554(.*)',
            destination: '/experiences/430-lp-v-fm',
            permanent: true,
        }
    ]
}
```